# Redirect url to mobile when user agent detects

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, user-agent

I want to write a rule
when the user agents detects mobile or iphone or ipod, the url should include m in the url
From http://domain.com/shop/abc.jsp to
http://domain.com/shop/m/abc.jsp

and vice versa
If the user agent is not mobile or ipod or iphone and if the url has already "/shop/m" it should be removed

Comment: and vice versa
If the user agent is not mobile or ipod or iphone and if the url has already "/shop/m" it should be removed (ie)
http://domain.com/shop/m/abc.jsp to
http://domain.com/shop/abc.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Detecting mobile user agents on apache rewrite level is not as reliable but you could find some code to start here: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/download/apache – this is not only iphone but all mobile devices...

You could develop from this fragment on and build a rule which redirects as you wish. Help on redirects on apache could be found for example here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html